# Python BeautifulSoup parsing / crawl table

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For my own interest, I want to crawl the table of properties from `"https://thinkimmo.com/search?noReset=true"`. After having clicked on "TABELLE" (TABLE) you can see all properties listed in a table.

With the following code I am able to see the table:

```
driver.get("https://thinkimmo.com/search?noReset=true")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/button[2]/span[1]').click()
```

Now I am able to crawl some parts of the table with the following code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
htmltable = soup.find('table', { 'class' : 'MuiTable-root' })
def tableDataText(table):       
    rows = []
    trs = table.find_all('tr')
    headerow = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in trs[0].find_all('th')] # header row
    if headerow: # if there is a header row include first
        rows.append(headerow)
        trs = trs[1:]
    for tr in trs: # for every table row
        rows.append([td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.find_all('td')]) # data row
    return rows
list_table = tableDataText(htmltable)
list_table
```

The result however is not what I expect. I only get the first 7 headings, but all other headings are not returned.

After I had a closer look at the HTML of the webpage I am not sure how to get all headings and results of the table.

I am looking forward to solving the problem of getting only some parts of the heading. And more closely I am interested in why I am failing.

What I see in the result of `table = soup.find("table")` is that after the 7th heading title the table closes.

Thanks in advance.

Steffen

Answer (score 0):

The site uses a backend api you can edit to bulk download data:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

results = 1000

url = f'https://api.thinkimmo.com/immo?active=true&type=APARTMENTBUY&sortBy=publishDate,desc&from=0&size={str(results)}&grossReturnAnd=false&allowUnknown=false&excludePlatforms=ebk,immowelt&favorite=false&noReset=true&excludedFields=true&geoSearches=[]&averageAggregation=buyingPrice%3BpricePerSqm%3BsquareMeter%3BconstructionYear%3BrentPrice%3BrentPricePerSqm%3BrentPricePerSqm%3BrunningTime&termsAggregation=platforms.name.keyword,60'

resp = requests.get(url).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(resp['results'])
df.to_csv('thinkimmo.csv',index=False)
print('Saved to thinkimmo.csv')
```

This is alot of unstructured data but should help. If you want to inspect what is in this api call and only get certain parts of the returned JSON then you can open your browser's Developer Tools - Network - fetch/XHR and reload the page to see all the backend requests fire. You are looking for one that starts "immo?" take a look at the Payload and Preview to see all the data. That's what we are scraping above.

Comment: Note how I edited the API's url by forcing it to give the first 1000 results, normally api's are protected from this type of thing and you have to loop over the pages only getting 20 results at a time. Very rare that you can do this in bulk like this and download their whole inventory